# Do estimated probabilities obtained after logistic regression sum up to the total number of observed successes?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood

I have a sequence of observed outcomes from independent but not identically distributed Bernoulli trials, and some covariate data. I perform logistic regression, and use it to estimate the probability of each trial succeeding. If I sum these estimates up, do they always add up to the total number of observed successes?

I know that in the absence of covariate data, the MLE of the constant term is the number of successes divided by the number of trials.

Comment: i mean, summing estimated probabilities for all observations, i.e. successes and failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming there is an intercept in the model, then the fitted probabilities sum to the number of ones in the sample.  This can be seen from the likelihood equations.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that it isn't true for the probit model.